# Overlay Color Blend in OpenGL ES / iOS / Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to apply BlendModes to a GreyScale image in order to have reusable static resources

I've been searching in the internet for hours and I did my own tests but I didn't find any solution.

I started with this image:

[image]

And the basic idea was to draw a rectangle over it in a certain color and apply a blending mode to the image only where the alpha is 1.0

Here is the Code (this is part of a Cocos2d project although I think it can be applied to generic OGL ES):

```
-(void)draw
{
    [super draw];

    glBlendColor(0,255,0,255);

    glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_SRC_COLOR);
    glColor4ub(255, 0, 255, 255);
    glLineWidth(2);
    CGPoint vertices2[] = { ccp(0,100), ccp(100,100), ccp(100,0) };
    [ DrawingHelper  drawPolygonWithPoints:vertices2 points:3 closePolygon:YES];

}
```

*Draw helper is the logic to draw the triangle.

```
+(void)drawPolygonWithPoints:(CGPoint *)poli points:(int)points closePolygon:(BOOL)closePolygon
{
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, poli);

    if( closePolygon )
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points);
    else
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, points);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

And here some results:

[image]
[image]

As you can see is a good approximation but this two images has error:

**OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]**

My Questions are:

1. How can I remove or fix this error?
2. How can keep only the alpha of the image (shield) and apply the blend overlay color?

[Update]This is an example of what I would like (with the correct blends):

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a "photoshopped" image of what you desire? When I work with artists it is much easier to work out a shader or postprocessing filter from a photoshop file with all the layers, than a textual description. You know, one picture → 1000 words.

Comment: Done @datenwolf, Hope it helps.

Comment: A word of caution if your intention is to use that banner in your app: the banners of a football team are trademarks. You may not use them in any way you wish. For example, it would very likely be a trademark violation to use the banner in a way that advertises your app, or makes it seem official, or something similar. Some fair use may apply, for example displaying the league results with team banners in a sports app, but even this may require approval by the FIFA, UEFA or other organisation.

Comment: No, this is only testing assets :) Thanks for the advise @LearnCocos2D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> apply a blending mode to the image only where the alpha is 1.0

This sounds like an application for alpha testing. Only that I'd first draw the rectangle and then make the alpha test fail for equal 1.0 (or greater than 0.99 to allow for some margin). This doesn't require blending.

---

#### Edit for updated question

Desired results:

> [image]

I think you mixed up Multiply and Overlay captions up there.

In all those cases this is done using either

- `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST); glAlphaFunc(GL_GEQUAL, 0.995);` // not using 1.0 for some margin

or

- `glEnable(GL_BLEND); glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

The effects are not created by setting the blend function or mode, but by texture environment or shader.

The "*Overlay*" (actually multiply) effect corresponds to the GL_MODULATE texture environment mode. Or in terms of a shader `gl_FragColor = texture2D(...) * color;`.

"*Lighten*" is `min(texture2D(...), color);`

"*Multiply*" (actually overlay) is `gl_FragColor = 1. - (1.-color*texture2D(...))*(1.-color);`

"*Soft Light*" is `gl_FragColor = (1. - (1.-texture2D(...))*(1.-color))*k + b;` (k and b choosen parameters).

Comment: Yes, you are right on the blend modes (updated) I cannot make it work  for now, seems alpha is not working but I am kind of newbie so it's probably my fault. Seems shaders would be a better option right? I don't know If I will be able to apply it to Cocos2D but I'll keep trying I need more information on how things are rendered / computed

Comment: Your overlay function may work but does not give the same effect as in Photoshop. The Photoshop formula is `((base.r < 0.5) ? (2.0 * base.r * overlay.r) : (1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - base.r) * (1.0 - overlay.r))),...` I am trying to overlay a texture with transparent and semi-transparent pixels and the result in those regions is almost black. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dex: There's a conditional in that. You'll need a shader for this one (well, you could use a very convoluted multipass method, by why bother?)

Comment: Yes, I am using a shader, however the result is not as expected. The transparent regions appear almost black. The method you posted also has a dark result. Could this be because I'm using a PNG for my texture?

Comment: Another thing I've discovered too is that GL_ALPHA_TEST is no long available in OpenGL ES 2

Comment: @Dex: Yes, because you're doing it in the shader now using a if statement to `discard` the fragment.

Comment: You probably found this already but you should use the rgb part according to the calculation and the use the alpha part from the original image. something like

temp = overlayCalculation...;
gl_FragColor = vec4(temp.rgb, texture1.a);