# OpenGL ES Overlay Blend Mode with Point Sprites

Tags: graphics, opengl-es

I'm trying to emulate Photoshop's Overlay blend mode on a point sprite. Is this possible in OpenGL ES?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8771413/1086804)

Comment: No, that doesn't deal with point sprites. I'm not sure how to access the background texture using a point sprite. I think I need to use an OpenGL blend mode.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - This might help you along:

Please note: I *do not* take credit for the code below; I found it on the powervr forums: http://www.imgtec.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=949

```
uniform sampler2D s_renderTexture;
uniform sampler2D s_overlayMap;
varying mediump vec2 myTexCoord;

void main()

{
     //Get the Texture colour values
     lowp vec3 baseColor = texture2D(s_renderTexture, myTexCoord).rgb;
     lowp float overlayTexture = texture2D(s_overlayMap, myTexCoord).r;
     lowp vec3 finalMix = baseColor + (overlayTexture - 0.5) * (1.0 - abs(2.0 * baseColor - 1.0));

     //Set the Fragments colour

     gl_FragColor = vec4( finalMix, 1.0 );

}
```

Sure, call this before rendering the point sprites:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

This should result in additive blending.

Here's a visual reference on the different blending mode combinations:
http://zanir.wz.cz/?p=60&lang=en

It's an old page, but it's a nice reference.

For more on opengl-es blending : http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml

Comment: What about for semi-transparent pixels? The Photoshop blend mode is a little different than OpenGL's and uses this formula `((base.r < 0.5) ? (2.0 * base.r * overlay.r) : (1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - base.r) * (1.0 - overlay.r))),...`